# How do I obtain TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION for an aribitrary timezone?

Tags: windows, winapi

In Windows, if I need a `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` struct for the current time zone, I can just call [GetTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  But what API do I use to get the `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` for an arbitrary time zone that is not the current time zone?

Answer (score 2):

Time zone information is on registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones`. You can load `TZI` value and it is exactly what you are looking for, see [TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, remarks.

Comment: It's not that simple, the Dynamic DST entries are very important.  Samoa hopped across the International Date Line last year :)

Comment: Correct, and `Dynamic DST` is also on registry under the same key.